# Toggle display of two elements only in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to toogle the display of two elements using this piece of code:

```
$('.annu-numtel-btn').click(function()
{
$('.annu-numtel-btn').toggleClass('hidden');
$('.annu-numtel').toggleClass('visible hidden');
});
```

and this html :

```
<p class="annu-numtel-btn visible ">Afficher le n° de téléphone</p>
<p class="annu-numtel hidden">Tél. : 01 31 32 45 78</p>
```

It's working but if I have multiple elements on the same page, it switches all elements, I just want to switch the one I clicked. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to target the element which is clicked in this way.

```
$('.annu-numtel-btn').click(function()
{
  $(this).toggleClass('hidden');
  $(this).next().toggleClass('visible hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this)` to access currently clicked element:

```js
    $('.annu-numtel-btn').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('hidden');
      $('.annu-numtel').toggleClass('hidden');
    });
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="annu-numtel-btn">Afficher le n° de téléphone</p>
<p class="annu-numtel hidden">Tél. : 01 31 32 45 78</p>
```